# mosquitto_sub gives certificate verify failed error

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I get the following error when I try to subscribe to a topics using by certs:

Command:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -v --capath <path_to_file>/xxx.pem --cert <path_to_file>/yyy.pem.crt  --key <path_to_file>/zzz.pem.key -h "<my_endpoint>" -p 8883 -t "<my_topic>"


Client (null) sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

I have checked the permission of the certificates and also provided the correct paths, but still not sure why I am hitting this error.

Comment: `--capath` should point to a directory `--cafile` should be used if pointing to a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments

- `--capath` is used to point to a directory full of CA certificates
- `--cafile` is used to point to a single certificate file

From the man page

> `--cafile`
>
> Define the path to a file containing PEM encoded CA certificates that are trusted. Used to enable SSL communication.
>
> See also --capath
>
> `--capath`
>
> Define the path to a directory containing PEM encoded CA certificates that are trusted. Used to enable SSL communication.
>
> For --capath to work correctly, the certificate files must have ".crt"
> as the file ending and you must run "openssl rehash "
> each time you add/remove a certificate.
>
> See also --cafile